# Puedo ejecutar una función y luego renderizar el html (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un **index.html** y en este tengo enlazado un **app.js.**

Lo que necesito realizar es antes de que se renderice el archivo **.html**, requiero incluir unos div de manera dinámica, para traer los datos utilizo **app.js**, y esto ya lo hace bien.

El problema es que debo primero ejecutar la función app.js, para que mi index.html quede completo como lo deseo cargar,y luego renderizarlo.

En este momento, se renderiza el html, luego se ejecuta la función.
No sé realmente si haya una manera de hacerlo, pues porque el **app.js** está dentro del **index.html.**

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: Si adjuntas código tal vez te puedan dar una respuesta más concreta y especifica.

Comment: Intenta adjuntar el `<script>` de JS en el `<head>` o al principio del `<body>`. De esa manera se va a cargar primero el Javascript y luego lo demás de HTML. Saludos